# Tangent of two parabolas

Tags: quadratics, tangent-line

Please, help.
We have two parabolas:

$$1.\;\; y^2 = x$$
$$2. \;\;y = 2x^2$$
How to calculate common tangent line for them?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A(a^2,a)$ and $B(b,2b^2)$ be the points on $C_1:y^2=x$ and $C_2:y=2x^2$ respectively.

Equation of tangent of $C_1$ at $A$:

\begin{align*}
  ay &= \frac{x+a^2}{2} \\
  y &= \frac{x}{2a}+\frac{a}{2} \quad \cdots \cdots \: (1)
\end{align*}

Equation of tangent of $C_2$ at $B$:

\begin{align*}
  \frac{y+2b^2}{2} &= 2bx \\
  y &= 4bx-2b^2  \quad \cdots \cdots \: (2)
\end{align*}

Comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$,

$$
\left \{
  \begin{array}{rcl}
    \frac{1}{2a} &=&  4b \\
    \frac{a}{2} &=& -2b^2 \\
  \end{array}
\right.$$

$$\frac{1}{4}=-8b^3 \implies b=-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{32}}$$

The common tangent is

$$y=-\sqrt[3]{2} x-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{128}}$$

**Useful fact:**

> Equation of tangent for conics $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ at the point $(x',y')$ is given by
>
> $$ax'x+h(y'x+x'y)+by'y+g(x+x')+f(y+y')+c=0$$

Comment: Right, brilliant! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint...Let the tangent be $y=mx+c$.

Solve this simultaneously with the first parabola to create a quadratic which must have double roots. Apply the condition that the discriminant is zero to make an equation for $m$ and $c$.

Repeat this with the second parabola and solve the simultaneous equations for $m$ and $c$.

Comment: Excellent hint! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to see that the tangent to the second parabola at $(t,2t^2)$ is
$$
y-2t^2=4t(x-t)
$$
that is,
$$
y=4tx-2t^2
$$
Substituting into the first one, we get
$$
(4tx-2t^2)^2=x
$$
that becomes
$$
16t^2x^2-(16t^3+1)x+4t^4=0
$$
which must have zero discriminant:
$$
(16t^3+1)^2-16^2t^6=0
$$
Solve and substitute.

Comment: Awesome! I've learn a lot from your explanation. Thank you!